# Connect4 in Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, minimax

Ok so I've been following this tutorial on Connect4 in java and I've tried to modify it to fit what I already had and to fit into libgdx. After implementing it, i have a few odd problems.

Problem 1: After i make the first move, the computer fills the entire bottom row with his chips and then makes his first move.

Problem 2: The computer isn't displaying any A.I. and simply starts at the first column and first row available and places a chip there. The computer will keep following this pattern.

Problem 3: My winning checker no longer realizes if I have won the game but does realize when the computer has won. When I first designed the game I started by having the computer place chips at random (for testing) and my winning checker worked for the computer and for myself.

The article I followed was here: [Connect4 in Java](https://johannes89.wordpress.com/2014/02/09/teaching-a-computer-to-play-connect-four-using-the-minimax-algorithm/)

Here is my code.

ConnectFour.java

```
package com.comp452.tme31;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class ConnectFour extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor {

    // Create final ints for number of columns and rows in game.
    protected final static int COLUMNS = 7;
    protected final static int ROWS = 6;
    protected final static int TILESIZE = 64;

    // Create boolean to determine if player can take a turn.
    protected boolean playersTurn = true;

    // Create boolean for gameover.
    protected boolean gameOver = false;

    // Create boolean for winners.
    private boolean winner = false;

    // Sprite batch for texture drawing.
    SpriteBatch batch;
    // Create textures to represent board and player pieces.
    Texture drawingTile, empty, player, computer;

    // Create 2D array to hold game board.
    private final static int[][] gameBoard = new int[COLUMNS][ROWS];

    public static int[][] getGameBoard() {
        return gameBoard;
    }

    // Create variables to display status message.
    BitmapFont mainStatusDisplay;
    public static String mainStatusString;
    public static String winningString;

    // Create and set max depth for tree search
    private final int MAX_DEPTH = 4;

    // Create win, loss and nothing for zero sum game.
    private final float WIN = 1f;
    private final float LOSE = -1f;
    private final float TIE = 0f;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        empty = new Texture("empty.jpg");
        player = new Texture("player.jpg");
        computer = new Texture("computer.jpg");

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);

        // Initialize display for status messages.
        mainStatusDisplay = new BitmapFont();
        mainStatusString = "Player's Turn";
        winningString = "";
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        update();
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        drawBoard();
        mainStatusDisplay.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        mainStatusDisplay.draw(batch, mainStatusString, 32, 416);
        batch.end();
    }

    public void drawBoard() {

        for (int i = 0; i < COLUMNS; i ++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
                if (gameBoard[i][j] == 0) {
                    drawingTile = empty; 
                }
                else if (gameBoard[i][j] == 1) {
                    drawingTile = player;
                }

                else if (gameBoard[i][j] == 2) {
                    drawingTile = computer;
                }
                batch.draw(drawingTile, i * 64, j * 64);
            }
        }
    }

    // Method update handles updates to game logic.
    public void update() {
        // If it's gameover, end the game.
        if (gameOver) {
            // Set players turn to true to prevent computer from taking another turn.
            playersTurn = true;
            // Set status message to winning message;
            mainStatusString = winningString;
            // Disable input processor to prevent player from taking another turn.
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null);
        }        

        // If it's not players turn, call computersTurn.
        else if (!playersTurn) {
            mainStatusString = "Computer's Turn";
            computersTurn();
        }

        if (checkForWin(1) && checkForWin(2)) {
            gameOver = true;
        }
    }

    public void computersTurn() {
        double maxScore = 2. * Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int xValue = 0;

        // Search the gameboard and find the best move.
        for (int x = 0; x < COLUMNS; x++) {
            // If x column is a value move...
            if (canMove(x)) {
                // Set score of move from function.
                double score = moveScore(x);

                // If score is greater than max score...
                if (score > maxScore) {
                    // Set score to max score and xValue to column.
                    maxScore = score;
                    xValue = x;
                    // If the score is a win, break from loop.
                    if (score == WIN) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Set the piece for player at column as x.
        setPiece(2, xValue);

        // Set players turn and string status.
        playersTurn = true;
        mainStatusString = "Player's Turn";
    }

    // Method moveScore determines the value of a move and returns it.
    public double moveScore(int xValue) {
        // Set the piece in place.
        setPiece(2, xValue);
        // Get the score and check it's value with alpha beta pruning.
        double score = alphaBetaPrune(MAX_DEPTH, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1);
        // Remove the piece.
        takeAwayPiece(xValue);

        return score;
    }

    public double alphaBetaPrune(int depth, double alpha, double beta, int whoPlayed) {
        winner = checkForWin(1) || checkForWin(2);
        // If we've reached the max depth of the tree or there is a winner...
        if (depth == 0 || winner) {
            double score;
            // If there is a winner...
            if (winner) {
                // If player is the winner...
                if (checkForWin(1)) {
                    // Set a losing score (Computer does not want player to win).
                    score = LOSE;
                }
                // Else this is a win for the computer...
                else {
                    // Set score to a win.
                    score = WIN;
                }
            }
            // Otherwise there is no winner...
            else {
                // Set score to TIE (0).
                score = TIE;
            }

            // Return score and remove depth level.
            return score / (MAX_DEPTH - depth +1);
        }

        // If computer is making the move...
        if (whoPlayed == 2) {
            // Iterate through gameboard.
            for (int x = 0; x < COLUMNS; x++) {
                // Check and see if next move can be made.
                if (canMove(x)) {
                    // Make move for computer to x.
                    setPiece(2, x);
                    // Set alpha equal to return from recursion step minus one depth level.
                    alpha = Math.max(alpha, alphaBetaPrune(depth - 1, alpha, beta, 1));
                    // Remove piece.
                    takeAwayPiece(x);
                    // Check returned alpha against beta and break from loop if beta is less than alpha.
                    if (beta <= alpha) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            // We're here if alpha is larger and we didn't break from loop.
            return alpha;
        }
        // Else if player is making move...
        else {
            // Iterate through gameboard.
            for (int x = 0; x < COLUMNS; x++) {
                // Check and see if next move can be made.
                if (canMove(x)) {
                    // Make move for player to x.
                    setPiece(1, x);
                    // Set beta equal to return from recursion step minus one depth level for beta.
                    beta = Math.min(beta, alphaBetaPrune(depth - 1, alpha, beta, 2));
                    // Remove piece.
                    takeAwayPiece(x);
                    // Check returned alpha against beta and break from loop if beta is less than alpha.
                    if (beta <= alpha) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            // We're here if alpha is larger than beta and we didn't break from loop.
            return beta;
        }
    }

    // Method setPiece takes two int values as parameters and places a piece on the game board.
    public void setPiece(int whoPlayed, int xValue) {
        // For loop to iterate through each row.
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
            // If row is empty...
            if (gameBoard[xValue][i] == 0) {
                // Place piece on the board.
                gameBoard[xValue][i] = whoPlayed;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Method takeAwayPiece takes two int values as parameters and removes a piece from the board.
    public void takeAwayPiece(int xValue) {
        // For loop to iterate through each row.
        for (int i = ROWS - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            // If row contains a piece..
            if (gameBoard[xValue][i] != 0) {
                // Remove piece.
                gameBoard[xValue][i] = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Method to determine if a move is valid
    public boolean canMove(int xValue) {
        // If the top spot in the given column is 0, return true.
        return (gameBoard[xValue][ROWS-1] == 0);
    }

    // Method checkForWin takes a flag and checks to see if that player has won the game.
    public boolean checkForWin(int whoPlayed) {
        // Create counter to check for 4 in a row.
        int win = 0;
        // Iterate through gameboard and count pieces in a row.
        for (int y = 0; y < ROWS; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < COLUMNS; x++) {
                // If piece is player who is checking, increment counter.
                if (gameBoard[x][y] == whoPlayed) {
                    win++;
                }
                // Not in a row, set counter to 0.
                else {
                    win = 0;
                }
                if (win == 4) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            // If win counter is 4, winner.
            if (win == 4) {
                winningString = "Horizontal Win for Player " + whoPlayed;
                return true;
            }
            // Else, reset win counter and check next column.
            else {
                win = 0;
            }
        }

        // Iterate through gameboard and count pieces in a column.
        for (int x = 0; x < COLUMNS; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < ROWS; y++) {
                // If piece is player who is checking, increment counter.
                if (gameBoard[x][y] == whoPlayed) {
                    win++;
                }
                // Not in a row, set counter to 0.
                else {
                    win = 0;
                }
                if (win == 4) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            // If win counter is 4, player won.
            if (win == 4) {
                winningString = "Vertical Win for Player " + whoPlayed;
                return true;
            }
            // Else, reset win counter and check next column.
            else {
                win = 0;
            }
        }

        // Iterate through gameboard and count pieces in a diagonal row, left to right.
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
                // If piece is player who is checking, check next piece diagonally.
                if (gameBoard[x][y] == whoPlayed) {
                    // Then check next diagonal piece.
                    if (gameBoard[x+1][y+1] == whoPlayed) {
                        // Then check next diagonal piece.
                        if (gameBoard[x+2][y+2] == whoPlayed) {
                            // Then check last diagonal piece.
                            if (gameBoard[x+3][y+3] == whoPlayed) {
                                // Set winning message to player won and set gameover flag.
                                winningString = "Diagonal Win (LR) for Player " + whoPlayed;
                                // Exit function.
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Iterate through gameboard and count pieces in a diagonal row, right to left.
        for (int x = 3; x < COLUMNS; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
                // If piece is player who is checking, check next piece diagonally.
                if (gameBoard[x][y] == whoPlayed) {
                    // Then check next diagonal piece.
                    if (gameBoard[x-1][y+1] == whoPlayed) {
                        // Then check next diagonal piece.
                        if (gameBoard[x-2][y+2] == whoPlayed) {
                            // Then check last diagonal piece.
                            if (gameBoard[x-3][y+3] == whoPlayed) {
                                // Set winning message to player won and set gameover flag.
                                winningString = "Diagonal Win (RL) for Player " + whoPlayed;
                                // Exit function.
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Iterate through gameboard and if no 0 slots remain, game is a tie.
        for (int x = 0; x < COLUMNS; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < ROWS; y++) {
                // If a 0 slot remains, return.
                if (gameBoard[x][y] == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        // If we're here, then there was no winners and no slots left.
        winningString = "Tie Game";
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
        if (playersTurn) {
            if (button == Input.Buttons.LEFT) {
                if (canMove(x / TILESIZE)) {
                    setPiece(1, x / TILESIZE);
                    playersTurn = false;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int i, int i1, int i2) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int i, int i1) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int i) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int i) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int i) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char c) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I was able to track down the source of the win checker error. In my update method I was checking with an && symbol, which meant that if either boolean failed the expression failed and since the player AND the computer can't both win, it would always return false. I changed it to an OR (||) and then suddenly the win checker works AND now the A.I. works as well. The only problem is still the first one where the computer places an entire row of pieces right off the start.

Answer (score 0):

So after the first fix, it was fairly easy to narrow down what the problem was for the other problem. In my takeAwayPiece method, it wasn't removing anything on the bottom row so when the A.I calculated it's next move, its testpieces it was placing at the bottom didn't work.

So in the takeAwayPiece method, i changed it to the following

```
  // Method takeAwayPiece takes two int values as parameters and removes a piece from the board.
    public void takeAwayPiece(int xValue) {
        // For loop to iterate through each row.
        for (int i = ROWS; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.println(i);
            // If row contains a piece..
            if (gameBoard[xValue][i-1] != 0) {
                // Remove piece.
                //System.out.println("Piece at column " + xValue + " " + i);
                gameBoard[xValue][i-1] = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

You might notice that the difference is that i starts = to ROWS instead of ROWS -1 and then i was checking against x-1 instead of x (Previously i just tried changing the condition from i > 0 to i = 0 but that had some crazy strange results).